# How to create a cookie and write a numeric value?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Could you please create [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (with tiny bit html) that creates a cookie and writes a numeric value in the cookie and then a function that reads the value of the cookie and then a condition that if it is a certain value, it displays an image?

Note the function that writes will need to always rewrite over the previous value.

Help me to do this. I'm awaiting great replies.

Give me the code here friends.
That's great for me.

Comment: someone is trolling with your account or what ?

Comment: @TheBrain: I assumed that too looking how much better other questions were asked from OP. Not all but some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setCookie(name,value,days){
    var expires='';
    if (days){
        var date=new Date();
        date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000) );
        expires='; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie= name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
}
function getCookie(name){
    var nameEQ = name + '=';
    var ca=document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c=ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ)===0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
    return null;
}
function deleteCookie(name){
    setCookie(name,'',-1);
}
```

setting your cookie

```
var value = 1001; // number of cookies to eat
setCookie('yourcookiename', value, 1);
```

getting your cookie

```
var cookievalue=parseInt( getCookie('yourcookiename'), 10);
//do your stuff here..
//i.e. show a img with jquery
if (cookievalue==1001) $('#yourImgID').show();
```

but think about, the if-check has to be done after you set allready your cookie

your html markup somewhere

```
<img id='yourImgID' src='superpictuefromsweetcookies.jpg'>
```

your css markup, so that it is not shown if your page loads
otherwise it is allready visible and there is nothing to be done to show it.

```
#yourImgID {
    display:none;
}
```

deleting if not used anymore

```
deleteCookie('yourcookiename');
```

eating cookie

```
//go and buy me some!! :)
```

Comment: how to do this in wordpress site?

Comment: buy a coder :) who goes thru all your template php files.
this is another thread. but anyway you could place all that code javascript, html and css code inside your header.php or in your templates.